# Loading stuck for `useSubscription` method in @apollo/react-hooks

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, apollo, race-condition, apollo-client

I sometimes get a race condition when trying to use `onSubscription` hook from `@apollo/react-hooks` package in the following way.

```
let { data, loading, error } = useSubscription(MY_SUBSCRIPTION)
if (loading) return 'Loading...';
if (error) return 'Error...';

...
```

When I load the page, most of the time `data` gets filled perfectly and eventually loading will turn `false`, but every ~5th try there's some kind of race condition where `loading` stays `true` forever and `data` is `undefined`.

GraphQL query:

```
export const EXERCISE_SUBSCRIPTION = gql`
    subscription {
      exercises {
        id
        title
        tasks {
          id
          title
          start_time
          end_time
        }
      }
    }
`;
```

Package version is the (currently) latest:
`@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.1.0-beta.0"`, but I have also tried with previous versions.

Has anyone experienced something similar and know how to solve it?
If you run into this issue, I found a workaround hack. You can see that when I add the callback option `onSubscriptionData`, the data **IS** present in there, but somehow does not end up in the `data` object outside.

```
  // <HACK>
  // sometimes data object is empty, but onSubscriptionData is filled.
  // in that case use data from onSubscriptionData method.

  const [dataFromCb, setDataFromCb ] = useState(null)
  let { data, loading } = useSubscription(INJECT_SUBSCRIPTION, {
    onSubscriptionData: (res) => {
      setDataFromCb(res.subscriptionData.data)
    },
  });
  if (loading && !dataFromCb) return 'Loading...';
  data = (data === undefined) ? dataFromCb : data;

  // </HACK>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I do believe I found the answer to this one, but to verify, you may need to double check and/or post your query code. Apparently Apollo is trying to marry up the data as it arrives, and it uses the `id` fields to do that by default. I had a query that was missing those `id`s in some nested layers of my structure, and when I put them in, this error has disappeared. It wasn't until I ran into [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52773365/apollo-client-network-error-typewriteerror) that I found the resources that pointed me in the right direction.

For reference: https://github.com/apollographql/react-apollo/issues/1003

Comment: I included my GraphQL query. As I have id's (primary keys in my Hasura schemas) for both return types, it's probably a different issue that the one you mentioned.

Comment: @MadisPukkonen Yeah, I'm starting to see the issue again too. It would appear this is still an open issue.

Comment: Anyone got the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with `useSubscription` loading stuck. Afterwards noticed that I kept this hook in the child component, so moved it on the same level (parent component) with the `useQuery` which triggered subscriptions on the server. So in my case it was React rendering issue which affected such a behaviour.